# .htaccess RewriteRule seems not to work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a problem with my .htaccess here and altough I searched the web and tried many things, I could not find any solution...

I have a wordpress-installation with enabled permalinks. Additional to that, I need to rewrite another URL on this wordpress-installation, which does not belong to WP.

If a user browses to `http://www.URL.com/?page_id=30&tag=all&filterCategory=6\%23Jackets`, I'd like to show `http://www.URL.com/jackets.html` as URL. There should also be the possibility to directly browse to `http://www.URL.com/jackets.html`.

My .htaccess looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^jacket\.html$ http://www.URL.com/?page_id=30&tag=all&filterCategory=6\%23Jackets [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does anyone have any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress rewrite rules are redirecting any requests to non-existant files through WordPress. The rewrite rule responsible for this, `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`, is marked with [L], indicating that no more rules are to be processed after it. In order for your rule to work, it must be placed before the WordPress rules, but after the line `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: Thanks for you idea, but the rule does not work, even if I put it between "RewriteEngine On" and "RewriteBase /". I also tried to out it above the whole Wordpress-Block (before #BEGIN Wordpress), but this also did not work (I used "RewriteEngine On" before the rule).Could it be that there is a problem with special characters in the URL?

Comment: I haven't personally come across any problems with special characters whilst using MOD_REWRITE, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's not the problem. Also, I was probably being unclear as to what I meant - it needs to be put after `RewriteBase /`, but before any rewrite rules. Plus, if you're not trying to change the domain, `index.php?page_id=30&tag=all&filterCategory=6\%23Jackets` might be a better target for your rewrite rule. Hope this helps.